# Prevent jQuery widget event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets

I'm using Twitter bootstrap "TimePicker" widget. This widget has behavior of increasing/decreasing time when ".keydown" event is fired.

I need to block this default behavior. How I could achieve that?

Currently I try to intercept and block events on html input element directly. I see that .keydown events are intercepted and prevented, but TimePicker .keydown event still fires:

```
    $('#timeInput').keydown(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
            arrow = { up: 38, down: 40 };

        switch (keyCode) {
            case arrow.up:
                window.debug.info("Key Up prevented");
                event.preventDefault();
                break;
            case arrow.down:
                window.debug.info("Key Down prevented");
                event.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    });
```

Can I override "TimePicker" control default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove keydown behavior anytime doing:

```
$('#timeInput').unbind('keydown');
```

or right after the widget initialization:

```
$('#timeInput').timepicker(options).unbind('keydown');
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to disable "keydown" event, but I need to override widgets default "keydown" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you're sending the `event` named `e`, just change this:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to that:

```
e.preventDefault();
```